# Codeigniter HMVC Error Ajax from folder outside from application

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, hmvc

i have this structure

- aplication

  - controllers
  - modules
  - any modules from proyect
- themes

  - default
  - view
  - modules
  - landing

    - search_in_model.php ( ajax.... url: "< ? php echo 
      base_url('Suggestions/hotelbedsHotels');  ? > ",
      )

this ajax get a 404 error..

I think it calls application/controllers but I understand that in HMVC I have to call a module?

my question is .. Can I call application/controlles for frontend and for backend call your module ..?

Thanks..